# Joint Bank Account

Tags: banking

I have a joint bank account with my sister that requires both signatures to withdraw money. She recently opened a personal account at the same bank. She transferred all the money into her personal account. Is there anything I can do to get my share of the money back? Can I take legal action against her?

Comment: How did she do it if it takes 2 signatures?

Comment: @TomTom It could be a mistake by the bank; it _might_ have been done through online banking. I don't have a joint account, but I _seem to remember_ something in the Ts&Cs for my UK bank that for a dual-sign joint account _both_ parties need to agree to the use of online banking, but once done, _either_ party can initiate transactions (in other words: online reverts to either/or signing). I don't _know_ if this is what happened here, but it's one possibility.

Comment: It is to check. Bank mistake: Talk to bank, get your moeny back from them (and they contact your sister). Otherwise... willing to take the sister possibly to court?

Comment: Why would you have a joint account with someone you don't trust?  Can you ask for the money back?  If not, you may want to count this as a costly lesson learned.

Comment: Legal questions should indicate which country, state, etc.

Comment: Are you *sure* that this joint account *requires both* signatures?

Comment: @PeteB: Perhaps Debbie NC trusted her sister up until the money transfer.  People will surprise you, and it's not always for the good.

Answer (score 6):

You're going to need to talk to your bank, or at least check the terms and conditions of the account. There are then a number of possibilities:

- your sister shouldn't have been allowed to do this transfer. Then the bank is in the wrong, and one would hope they would reverse the transfer without any fuss, though in practice maybe you'd have to make a fuss
- or, the account wasn't as restrictive as you thought, in which case your sister was perfectly entitled to transfer *her* money (in a joint account the money is *both* people's money) from one account to another
- if this is the case *and the bank mis-sold the account to you*, representing it as restrictive in the way you wanted when in fact it isn't, you may have the possibility of obtaining redress from the bank for this mis-selling. But this seems like a long shot.

In any event, this is all rapidly approaching the point where you might want to consider a lawyer. I'm not one of those.

Comment: There is another possibility, which is that someone forged the OPs signature.

Comment: USA  North Carolina

Comment: No mistake.. Transferred the money and then withdrew it

Answer (score -1):

it is not the bank's fault if the mandate was that either of them can sign and withdraw money. But if it was stated that both were to sign before money can be withdrawn that is where the bank can be held accountable.

Comment: This doesn't seem to add anything of value to the better answer already provided by AakashM.